# Call a function once object is defined in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

**first.js**

```
var obj = {
    id: 1,
    xyz: function(){

    }
};
```

I want to update the id and call xyz function in second.js file. What is best way to do that?
As scripts will load asynchronously.

**second.js**

```
obj.xyz();
```

Comment: How are they loading asynchronously? Are you using a lazy loader script?

Comment: No, I am not. I guess all the scripts load asynchronously on page.

Comment: @Yogesh: No, they don't. With the markup you've given, they load *synchronously*.

Comment: If this dont work, there might be an other problem in your script...

Comment: Will this affect if I have put entire code in both JS in document.ready?

Comment: @Yogesh: jQuery will execute the ready callbacks in order. However, note that if you have `var obj = ...` inside your ready callback in `first.js`, it's no longer a global, and `second.js` can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

In a comment on the question, you've said you're not using any kind of script loader. That means that, given the markup you've quoted, `first.js` is loaded and executed first, and then `second.js` is loaded and executed. `second.js` will not be loaded and run until `first.js` is (or until `first.js` fails to load). So `second.js` can do just what you've shown; unless `first.js` completely fails to load, `obj` will be there and waiting.

---

**Original answer** based on claim in question that the scripts load asynchronously:

Well, the best way is to have some form of connection or messaging between the two.

But you *can* do it with polling.

second.js:

```
(function() {
    attempt();

    function attempt() {
        if (typeof obj !== "undefined") {
            // Got it!
            obj.xyz();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(attempt, 50);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: polling is probably not a good solution rather OP can fire callbacks once the object is ready.

Comment: @Abhidev: See the **first sentence** of the original answer: *"Well, the best way is to have some form of connection or messaging between the two."*

Answer (score 0):

Try to force obj definition to be "global" defining it in the window object

```
window.obj = {
    id: 1,
    xyz: function(){
        alert("hey!");
    }
}
```

then call

```
window.obj.xyz();
```

or

```
obj.xyz();
```

Comment: polluting the global scope is definitely not recommended.

Comment: defining an object with `var` directly on the window will also pollute the global scope

Answer (score -1):

add all our scripts at the bottom of the page inside body tag and your script will run just fine. If you are still unsure about it(there is no reason though) you can add your js call inside this : -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);
```

OR if you are using jquery then you can add your code inside this: -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question the OP asked. This talks about DOM elements; the OP's question is quite clearly about JavaScript objects created by the first script.